# How to make checkboxes 'checkable' only if another box is checked

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

So imagine I have 3 checkboxes,  1 'parent' checkboxes and 2 'child' checkboxes.

If the parent checkbox is checked, I want to be able to check either or both of the two child checkboxes.

If the parent checkbox is unchecked, I either of the two child checkboxes should not be checkable at all.

```
<div id="mycheckboxes">

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="parentcheckbox" name="parentcheckbox"
                 [(ngModel)]="parentcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="parentcheckbox1($event)">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description">
        </label>


        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox1" name="childcheckbox1"
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox1($event)">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description">
        </label>

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox2" name="childcheckbox2"
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox2" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox2($event)">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description">
        </label>

</div>
```

currently everyone of of these checkboxes are checkable, to reiterate the above, I am trying to make it so if parentcheckbox is checked, the two children are selectable, and if parent is unchecked, the two children are uncheckable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `component.ts` file add these lines:

```
  parentcheckbox1;
  childcheckbox1;
  childcheckbox2;
  isParentChecked = true;
  parentcheckbox(event) {
    this.isParentChecked = !event;
  }
```

and the HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="mycheckboxes">

  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="parentcheckbox" name="parentcheckbox"
                 [(ngModel)]="parentcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="parentcheckbox($event)">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        </label>


  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox1" name="childcheckbox1"
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox1($event)" [disabled]="isParentChecked">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        </label>

  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox2" name="childcheckbox2"
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox2" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox2($event)" [disabled]="isParentChecked">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        </label>

</div>
```

I made few changes in the file. Like missing closing tag of `span`, `parentcheckbox1` method renamed to `parentcheckbox` and added `disabled` in child checkboxes.
Here is the working stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5mpvv?file=src/app/app.component.html
Let me know if face any issue.

- New Update based on comments:
  `parentcheckbox` method:

```
 parentcheckbox(event, child1, child2) {
    this.isParentChecked = !event;
    if (!event) {
      child1.checked = false;
      child2.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

HTML Changes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="parentcheckbox" name="parentcheckbox"
                 [(ngModel)]="parentcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="parentcheckbox($event, child1, child2)">
```

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox1" name="childcheckbox1"
          #child1
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox1" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox1($event)" [disabled]="isParentChecked">
```

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcheckbox2" 
          #child2 name="childcheckbox2"
                 [(ngModel)]="childcheckbox2" (ngModelChange)="childcheckbox2($event)" [disabled]="isParentChecked">
```

Comment: this was great! really getting me in the right direction! Quick question, how would one deselect the child checkboxes if the parent is uncheck. as it stands now, parent is checked, and the both of the children are selected, then the parent is unchecked, the children are still checked, but disabled and permenantly checked. so by that I mean, how can i make it so if the parent is unchecked, the child boxes are also unchecked

Comment: Obviously there are different ways to do so. The solution I could think of now is get a reference of child checkboxes and pass it as argument in `parentcheckbox` method. Updating the answer and also updated the stackblitz accordingly.

Comment: @dros Glad! it helped. Could you accept the answer as accepted answer if it resolves your query?

Comment: is the parentcheckbox method in addition to the previous method you posted, or a replacement for the previous?

Comment: Replacement of the previous one if you want the solution you asked for in the comment/

Comment: thank you this worked beautifully, accepting this answer. Thank you so much for the detail answer!

Answer (score 1):

In the parent change handler `parentcheckbox1()` set a property e.g. `disableChildCheckboxes` - to either `true` or `false`. Bind this to the `disabled` attribute of the child inputs using

```
<input [attr.disabled]="disableChildCheckboxes || null"
```

Also, use distinct names for the handler functions and ngModel i.e not the same name for both

Answer (score -3):

**For people using VanilaJS (Not Angular)**

EDIT: I haven't used Angular so I didn't realize that there is a better way to do this. I will leave this answer up for those wanting a way to do this in VanillaJS.

I have tried three almost identical approaches here, all using javascript. For all of them you will need to add the `disabled` attribute to the children and add an `onclick` attribute to the parent with the appropriate function copied into the page. If you only have one of these on your page than I would probably go for approach 1 or 2 otherwise I would use approach 3.

1. This just runs a function which checks if the parent is checked when you click on it and disables/enables the children accordingly.
   Add `onclick="toggle_children()"` to the parent checkbox.
2. This is similar to 1 but when you call the function you are also sending whether the box is checked of not so the if statement is not needed.
   Add `onclick="toggle_children1(this.checked)"` to the parent checkbox.
3. This is best if you are using multiple of these groups on a page. On each parent add `onclick="toggle_children2(this.checked, children_array)"` where children_array is an array containing the id's of all the children connected to that parent.

```js
// onclick="toggle_children()"
function toggle_children() {
  if (document.getElementById('parentcheckbox').checked) {
    document.getElementById('childcheckbox1').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('childcheckbox2').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('childcheckbox1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('childcheckbox2').disabled = true;
  }
}

// onclick="toggle_children1(this.checked)"
function toggle_children1(state) {
  document.getElementById('childcheckbox1').disabled = !state;
  document.getElementById('childcheckbox2').disabled = !state;
}

// onclick="toggle_children2(this.checked, ['childcheckbox1', 'childcheckbox2'])"
function toggle_children2(state, children) {
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(children[i]).disabled = !state;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="mycheckboxes">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="parentcheckbox" onclick="toggle_children2(this.checked, ['childcheckbox1', 'childcheckbox2'])">Parent
    </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="childcheckbox1" disabled>Child1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="childcheckbox2" disabled>Child2
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't. You're not using Angular at all. Don't directly access the DOM unless you really have to (and you don't have to).